# javascript variable to php variable

Tags: php, javascript, variables, date, client

I need to assign javascript client Date (examp. - 2012/02/03 16:00:00) to php variable. Any idea how? I was trying to use this lines and changing them in million different ways. But I just cant get it.

```
Today = new Date();
var date = ????
var date = "<?= $date ?>";
```

I solved it this way:

```
<input id="date" type="hidden" name="date">
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('date').value = Date();
</script>
```

But thank you very much all.

Comment: You want the client date in your php code? Not possible in the way you are doing it. Pay attention at how the client-server model works, you can't mix client logic and server logic that way.

Comment: Yes, now when I think about it's true. But if I wanted javascript date variable put into form, into hidden input how would I do that?

Comment: You can implement an ajax solution to make a call to your php script to pass the current client time to your server.

Comment: But if this form with hidden input is not in php but in html do I still need to use ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an input in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="clientDate">
```

if you are using jquery add this to set the client date input when the user submits the form

```
$(YOUR_FORM_SELECTOR).on("submit", function() {
  $("[name=clientDate]").val(new Date());
});
```

If you want to go with vanilla javascript [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001937/auto-insert-date-and-time-in-form-input-field)

Comment: To be honest I never used jQuery so I do not really know how? I just now am thinking about getting client side date(). Assigned it to html form to hidden input. Pass it by post to another page where php will take it as $_POST["#"].

Comment: follow the link in my answer...hope it helps

Comment: What would be an example form selector? Say I had a form like... `<form name="signup" id="signup1" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

you can't simply assign a javascript variable to a php variable. php runs on the serverside and is executed before javascript. 
you can however submit an ajax call with the value of your javascript variable to a php script.
you might wanna have a look at [jquery's post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function.

```
$.post("test.php", { yourDate: date } );
```

in your PHP script you'll be able to access the date with `$_POST['yourDate']`
you can also use a form and a hidden field as you say in your comment. 
in this case you can use (assuming you're using jQuery)

```
$('#id_of_input').val(date);
```

Comment: ok I'm gonna ask different way than. I have a form, I have a hidden input to which I would like to assign javascript variable. Is that possible? Concretely time.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert js variable to php variable and php variable to js variable

```
<script>
function jstophp(){


var javavar=document.getElementById("text").value;  

document.getElementById("rslt").innerHTML="<?php 
$phpvar='"+javavar+"'; 
echo $phpvar;?>";
}

function phptojs(){

var javavar2 = "<?php 

$phpvar2="I am php variable value";
echo $phpvar2;

?>";
alert(javavar2);
}

</script> 
<body>
<div id="rslt">
</div>


<input type="text" id="text" />
<button onClick="jstophp()" >Convert js to php</button>
<button onClick="phptojs()">Convert php to js</button>

PHP variable will appear here:
<div id="rslt2">
</div>

</body>
```

Demo: http://ibence.com/new.php