# Java Web application: How can I show system time generated at client side in the report

Tags: java, web-applications, jasper-reports

In every page, I want to display Date of print. I have used `new Date()`, but it is showing system time of server. I want to display current system time (client).

How can print this in *JR* report?

Comment: Are you talking about *JR Server* or about custom web-application hosted on a some application server?

Comment: application server, for us it is located in different countries...

Comment: You can use applet for initializing datetime parameter on a client side. And then pass this parameter to the report

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an applet, you can use a little JavaScript.

See this question: [Auto insert date and time in form input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001937/auto-insert-date-and-time-in-form-input-field)

For example:

```
<form action="generate_report" method="post">
  <input id="report_date" name="report_date" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('report_date').value = Date();
</script>
```

Pass the value of `report_date` into the report's parameter list.