# Auto set time html

Tags: html, forms, time, types, set

I have a small problem. I have a form where I wish the time were to be written automatically, but I do not know how to do. 
I tried with:

```
<input type="time"/>
```

but the time is not inserted automatically. 
Does anybody know how to help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time type is not fully compatible yet, regardless if you want it to read the current date/time as of the time of execution you must populate the field from javascript.

```
<input type="time" id="time"> 
<script>
document.getElementById("time").value = Date();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The topic has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001937/auto-insert-date-and-time-in-form-input-field), use the Javascript Date() object. A description can be found on the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
<body>
   time: <input type="time" id='now'/>  
   <script>document.getElementById('now').value = Date().toString();</script>
</body>
```

Use toDateString() instead of toString() if you only want the date.