# Setting TextBox text as current year

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I am trying to set a Readonly textbox2 text property to current year.
I am  trying to set textbox2 text by using onchange() property on an above textbox1, this way after changing textbox2 text will be asigned as current year. Now the problem is, I have no idea how to work with date formats in jquery is to.
Here I am doing it like this `$("#<%=FromYear.ClientID%>").val(Date.now);` but its not giving me year.

Comment: if you want to set text property as year you need to write it .Text() instead of val()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Date() function to use.

**Example:**

```
$("#id.ClientID").val(new Date().getfullYear());
```

OR

```
$("#id.ClientID").val(new Date().getYear());
```

If you want to know more about Date() function and its attributes? check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001937/auto-insert-date-and-time-in-form-input-field)

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = new Date();

alert(s.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date.now` will return the function code of the `Date.now()` function:

```
console.log(Date.now);
> function () { [native code] }
```

You want `Date.getFullYear()`

```
$("#<%=FromYear.ClientID%>").val(Date.getFullYear());
```

Comment: All suggested answers are helpful and correct thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var today=new Date();

$('#DispalyDate').text("Full date=" + today.toDateString()); 
$('#FullYear').text("Full year=" + today.getFullYear()); 
$('#DayOfMonth').text("Day=" + today.getDate()); 
$('#GetMonth').text("Number of month=" + today.getMonth()); 

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DispalyDate"> </div>
<div id="FullYear"> </div>
<div id="DayOfMonth"> </div>
<div id="GetMonth"> </div>
```