# How to format date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date as "Thursday, 4 Aug 2011".  How do I format it to "yyyy/MM/dd"?  I have tried the codes:

```
var myDate =   dateText.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");
myDate = Date.parseExact(myDate, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

but none seem to work.  Help please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986657/how-do-i-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 1):

you may use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

here is a post on the subject : 
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

you also have this jquery plugin : 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat