# In Javascript how can i get todays date in this format yyyymmdd

Tags: javascript, date

Like i need to get todays date in format like 20120924 (yyyymmdd).How can i get this in javascript.

Comment: Duplicate so far [How do I format a Javascript Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986657/how-do-i-format-a-javascript-date?rq=1)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript it will help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a method to the date prototype, so you can use it on any date object:

```
Date.prototype.toMyString = function () {

    function padZero(obj) {
          obj = obj + '';
          if (obj.length == 1)
              obj = "0" + obj
          return obj;
    }

    var output = "";
    output += this.getFullYear();
    output += padZero(this.getMonth()+1);
    output += padZero(this.getDate());

    return output; 
}

var d = new Date();
alert(d.toMyString());  // Today

var otherDate = new Date(2012,0,1);
alert(otherDate.toMyString());​  //Jan 1 2012
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/4rk7K/10/

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
var rDate = (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
​var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear().toString();
var month = date.getMonth().toString();
var day = date.getDate().toString();

if (parseInt(month) < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (parseInt(day) < 10) day = "0" + day;

var parsedDate = year + month + day;
```

(edit)
Improved this function by making the day equate to the day of the month, rather than the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
date = new Date().toJSON().substr(0,10).split("-")
date = date[0] + date[1] + date[2]
```

Edit:
This will return the UTC date, not local date...

For local date, you could use:

```
date = new Date().toLocaleDateString().split("/");  // "M/D/YYYY"
date[0] = date[0].length == 1 ? "0" + date[0] : date[0];
date[1] = date[1].length == 1 ? "0" + date[1] : date[1];
date = date[2] + date[0] + date[1];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
document.write(curr_year + curr_month + curr_date);
```

That should give the right date:)

Comment: a little change.. document.write(curr_year +""+ curr_month +""+ curr_date); otherwise its a addition.

Comment: You would need to add zero-padding & adjust the month which will be 0 based