# Converting date from variable to MM-DD-YYY

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I have a function that takes an input and converts it to a date. I would like to get the date in the format `January 01, 2014`. The #date comes in with the form as `January 10 - January 25`.  I need to split these into two different dates (the start date and the end date). The #year comes in as `2014`

Not very experienced with JavaScript but trying to get this to work.

Here is my script:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var startDates = $('#date').val().split(" - ");
                    var year = $('#year').val();
                    var yearDec = parseInt(year, 10) + 1;
                    var payPdStart = startDates[0] + ' ' + year;
                    var payPdEnd = startDates[1] + ' ' + yearDec;
                    var startDate = Date.parse(payPdStart);
                    myStartDates = new Date(startDate);

                    var endDate = Date.parse(payPdEnd);
                    myEndDates = new Date(endDate);        })
})
```

The script outputs something like... Thu Dec 25 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
I want it to show Thursday Dec 25, 2014 ( I don't need any time portion)

Comment: What doesn't work in your script?

Comment: See this link to see how you can format a date using a pattern : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986657/how-do-i-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you are doing with the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var startDates = $('#date').val().split(" - ");
                var year = $('#year').val();
                var payPdStart = startDates[0] + ' '+ year;
                var payPdEnd = startDates[1] + ' ' + year;
                var startDate = Date.parse(payPdStart);
                myStartDates = moment(new Date(startDate)).format('MMMM DD, YYYY');
                var endDate = Date.parse(payPdEnd);
                myEndDates = moment(new Date(endDate)).format('MMMM DD, YYYY');
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

- use the methods of the Date-object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
- use Moment.js: http://momentjs.com/. It's a js-library that provides methods for parsing, manipulating and formatting dates
- use jQuery-Datepicker: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ for the whole task

Answer (score 0):

"July, 03 2014"

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

Number.prototype.pad = function() {
    return (this < 10) ? ("0" + this) : this;
}
var d = new Date(),
    h = monthNames[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDay().pad() + ", " + d.getFullYear();
```